# use angularjs http json result separately in scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I used Angularjs $http and $scope to get data from sql server and display it successfully in scopes with no problem. But when I tried to display http json result from separated function in the same scope nothing happened.

All I wanted to know. If I want to get json object in a parameter and select slice from it before displaying, should I make http request every time to do so or can I separate scope away from http request in independent function as shown below.

```
<%--Angular--%>
<script src="../Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>

    var jsonObj;
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

    app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
        $http.get('../C_Angular.asmx/ShowSlider')
        .then(function (response) {
            jsonObj = response.data; // this part work well and retrieve data as expected by tracing C_Angular.asmx code
        });
            Select_From_Json = function (x, y) { 
                $scope.Categories = jsonObj.slice(x, y); // but this part don't work when I press Button1 to call Select_From_Json 
            };
    });
</script>
```

When I press Button1 to call Select_From_Json fuction no displaying take place.

```
    <input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" onclick="Select_From_Json(2, 4)" />

    <div data-ng-app="myApp" data-ng-controller="myCtrl">

        <div data-ng-repeat="Cat in Categories">

            <div style="background-image: url('{{Cat.Cat_Pic}}');">
                <span>{{Cat.Cat_Name}}</span>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: Select_From_Json() is not set in $scope. To access it in the html set function  $scope.Select_From_Json, And move ng-app above the input

Comment: plus you need to use ng-click instead of onclick as @deblaton-jean-philippe pointed out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your button is outside the controllers scope. That is why the Select_From_Json is not executing properly.
Move the button inside the div where the controller is defined.

```
<div data-ng-app="myApp" data-ng-controller="myCtrl">
 <input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" onclick="Select_From_Json(2, 4)" />

    <div data-ng-repeat="Cat in Categories">

        <div style="background-image: url('{{Cat.Cat_Pic}}');">
            <span>{{Cat.Cat_Name}}</span>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

You also should be using ng-click for executing functions from a controller like so:

```
    <div data-ng-app="myApp" data-ng-controller="myCtrl">
 <input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" ng-click="select_From_Json(2, 4)" />

    <div data-ng-repeat="Cat in Categories">

        <div style="background-image: url('{{Cat.Cat_Pic}}');">
            <span>{{Cat.Cat_Name}}</span>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

And in the controller itself:

```
$scope.select_From_Json = function(x, y){
    $scope.Categories = jsonObj.slice(x, y);
}
```